# running FxCop in NAnt on VS 2010 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nant, fxcop

I'm trying to set up a CI tool using NAnt.
I have managed to have NAnt build the project
I've created the .FxCop file for the project, but when I inserted the FxCop commands in the Nant Build configuration, I received

```
[exec] Loading C:\projects\BuildingSolution\BuildingSolution.FxCop...
[exec] Failed loading FxCop project.
[exec] Error text: Project version is incompatible with current application version..
```

the project and solution is made from Visual Studio 2010 on .NET 4.0
NAnt version is 0.91-alpha2
FxCop version is 10

The settings that I inserted:

```
<target name="runFxCop">
<exec program="c:\devtools\fxcop10\fxcopcmd.exe" 
   commandline="/p:${FxCop.Filename}  /o:${Build.OutputFolder}Latest\fxcop-results.xml" 
   failonerror="false"/>
</target>
```

The error message says that the project is not supported, but I've seen posts that talks about FxCop supporting .Net 4.0. 
I'm not sure whether I'm configuring it wrong or it's not supported at the moment.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try running FxCop on the command line first - take NAnt out of the picture temporarily. Get FxCop working, then add the command line you used to the NAnt build script. FxCop 10 works fine on .NET 4/VS 2010 projects; we run it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `nant.settings.currentframework` property like this:

```
<property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-4.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ditto @TrueWill - try to get it running via the command line to ensure it works, then integrate it into your nant scripts.

However I have chosen an alternative method of running this analysis for my projects as the FxCop command line runner produces different results than the IDE Code Analysis runner (namely because FxCop doesn't support the new phoenix engine), and I wanted the build server to enforce the same rules as were run in the IDE.

I used the process as described in [this blog](http://kentb.blogspot.co.nz/2011_01_01_archive.html) to set up my environment. This also gave me the ability to relax the rules for my unit test projects. When the build task is run, the code analysis results are written to a `CodeAnalysisLog.xml` file for each project. My CI server then simply checks these logs for the report.